# How do I write an array to a range of cells after redimming the array?

Tags: arrays, vba

My goal is to select a column of about 300,000 cells and round each cell's value to two decimal places.

I found that looping an array is far faster than looping through cells.

It is much faster if I have the whole array post its data into the cells after the loop rather than during because again posting any data in a loop takes too much time.

**Is there a way to write all the values from the new array ("varArray") after the loop is completed?**

```vb
Sub RoundedTwoDecimalPlaces()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim MyArray() As Variant ' Declare dynamic array.
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim lStart As Double
    Dim lEnd As Double
        
    lStart = Timer
    
    LastRow = Cells(1, Selection.Column).End(xlDown).Row
    
    MyArray = Range("a1:a8").Value2
    
    ReDim MyArray(LastRow) ' Resize to x amount of elements.
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        MyArray(i) = Round(Cells(i, Selection.Column), 2) ' Initialize array.
    Next i
    
    ''this is where I can't get my array to post into the cells dynamically.
    Selection.Value = MyArray()
    
    ''to see the amount of time it takes to finish.
    '' My goal is to do 300,000 lines quickly
    lEnd = Timer
    
    Debug.Print "Duration = " & (lEnd - lStart) & " seconds"
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the array directly from the range and then restore the altered values:

```vb
Sub RoundedTwoDecimalPlaces()
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim lStart As Double
    Dim ws As Worksheet, col as Long
     
    Set ws = ActiveSheet   
    col = Selection.Column
    lStart = Timer
    
    With ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, col), ws.Cells(1, col).End(xlDown))
        arr = .Value
        For i = 1 to Ubound(arr, 1)
            arr(i, 1) = Round(arr(i, 1), 2)
        Next i 
        .Value = arr 
    end with
    
    Debug.Print "Duration = " & (Timer - lStart) & " seconds"
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it using @Tim Williams Code.

I had to loop it because the array has a max character limit.

Here is the finished code:

```
Sub loopthrough()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim arr1 As Variant
    Dim arr2 As Variant
    Dim lStart As Double
    Dim ws As Worksheet, col As Long
    
     

   LastRow = Cells(1, Selection.Column).End(xlDown).Row
 

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    col = Selection.Column
    lStart = Timer

   If LastRow < 30001 Then
   
    With ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, col), ws.Cells(1, col).End(xlDown))
        arr = .Value2
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        
        If IsNumeric(arr(i, 1)) Then
            arr(i, 1) = Round(arr(i, 1), 2)
        Else
            arr(i, 1) = arr(i, 1)
        End If
        
        Next i
        .Value2 = arr
    End With
   

Else ''if selection is more than 30,000 lines.
  
n = 1
Z = 30000
Do While Z < LastRow
    
      With ws.Range(ws.Cells(n, col), ws.Cells(Z, col))
        arr = .Value2
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        
        If IsNumeric(arr(i, 1)) Then
            arr(i, 1) = Round(arr(i, 1), 2)
        Else
            arr(i, 1) = arr(i, 1)
        End If
        
        Next i
        .Value2 = arr
      End With
    n = n + 30000
    Z = Z + 30000

Loop


      With ws.Range(ws.Cells(n, col), ws.Cells(n, col).End(xlDown))
        arr = .Value2
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
            
            If IsNumeric(arr(i, 1)) Then
            arr(i, 1) = Round(arr(i, 1), 2)
        Else
            arr(i, 1) = arr(i, 1)
        End If
        
        Next i
        .Value2 = arr
      End With
     
End If

 Debug.Print "Duration = " & (Timer - lStart) & " seconds"

End Sub
```